# configure gcc in RHEL5 - no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Tags: apache, gcc, compiler-construction, path, rhel5

I want to install Apache in RHEL5. While configuring *httpd-2.4.2* following error came:

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

So I downloaded *gcc-4.7.0* and tried configuring it. Still the same error is coming.

```
$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/httproot/gcc-4.7.0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

---

### Following are some of the status results:

- ```
  gcc --version
  bash: gcc: command not found
  ```
- ```
  rpm -qi gcc
  package gcc is not installed
  ```
- ```
  which gcc
  /usr/bin/which: no gcc in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/bin:/bin)
  ```
- ```
  whereis gcc
  gcc: /usr/libexec/gcc
  ```

---

I can't use `yum`. So please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: What's preventing you from using `yum`? Can you get the individual RPMs and install those manually?

Comment: My system is not registered with RHN.                            yum update
Loaded plugins: katello, product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update

Comment: I have tried installing rpms like gcc-3.4.3-9.EL4.src.rpm,gcc-4.1.2-50.el5.src.rpm rtc. Also I have tried with gcc-4.7.0 too.

Comment: No point in installing GCC source code, but a GCC binary should satisfy it.

Comment: GCC binary didnt work for me. The above ./configure result id the one I got when I tried configuring gcc-4.7.0. I referred to many forums, but didnt wokr for me.

Comment: install gcc using yum.You can use CentOS base repository

Comment: Thanks! But could you give more details on how to so the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all those helped me. I have succesfully make gcc work. I got rpm files for gcc and http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/5.8/x86_64/CentOS/

Comment: Hi, the above url goes to 404 page. please update the url

Answer (score 3):

I could not found any packages from the below URL

http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/5.8/x86_64/CentOS/

Finally found the solution :

yum groupinstall "Development tools"

or

yum install gcc glibc glibc-common gd gd-devel

Comment: I had already used "Development Tools", but the manual yum install fixed this issue for me on CentOS 5, thanks!